# Javascript window.open() function opens link without popup blocker

Tags: javascript

Javascript `window.open()` function opens link without popup blocker, I want to open some links from javascript `window.open()` function but it get blocked on firefox, chrome, safari.

How Can I unblock popup through javascript code so that it will opens up in new tab

My code is:

```
    function GoUrl(id) {
        var string = 'select#' + id + ' option:selected';
        var value = $(string).val(); 
        if (value != "links") {enter code here
           window.open(value, '_blank'); 
            window.focus();
        }
```

Comment: When do you call that function? You are not allowed to open new windows programmatically, the invocation must stem from a user input (e.g. a click)

Answer (score 4):

Just found the answer from a different thread, thought I shared this one with you guys, the **ONLY** way to bypass the popup blocker is through the **onclick** event, the problem I was having was that I had **onmousedown** instead, I just simply changed it to onclick, and boom! worked instantly!

Comment: This is the only correct answer here. "any" user-event will not work, otherwise spammers would use onmousemove to show popups. And speaking of "onmousedown" - I (and probably I'm not alone) really hate sites that attach click events to onmousedown, because I clearly see that the reaction happens even before I release the mouse button, and it slightly annoys. If for some reason onclick won't work for you, then onmouseup is a much better event. Just check for example how links work: they all work when you release the button, not just press...

Answer (score 2):

You should launch you function from user event. i.e: onclick or href:

```
 <a href="javascript:window.open('http://google.com');return false;"> open 2 </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't force it to open a new tab. The functionality is controlled by the browser entirely.

To avoid having your windows blocked, have the window open on any user event (like `onclick`).